# Google chart api Invalid row index . Should be in the range [0-4]

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to develop report for my organization for that I am using google charts I am using bar chart for my report.

Is is the java script code I am using to display chart if I hard code values in google.visualization.DataTable(); the bar chart renders properly. If I try to fetch values from java script object it shows error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlY1r.png)

The java script code i am using is

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  
  var obj = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($enroled_course) ?>');

 google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);

function drawMaterial() {

  //  alert(obj.toSource());

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Course Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Completion Percentage');
  
 data.addRows(20);

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {   
    var val = obj[key];
    var course_percent=val.id;
    var course_name=val.fullname;
   data.setCell(course_name,course_percent);
    //console.log(val);
  }
}


/*var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

// Declare columns
data.addColumn('string', 'Employee Name');
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Hire Date');

// Add data.
data.addRows([
  ['Mike', {v:new Date(2008,1,28), f:'February 28, 2008'}], // Example of specifying actual and formatted values.
  ['Bob', new Date(2007,5,1)],                              // More typically this would be done using a
  ['Alice', new Date(2006,7,16)],                           // formatter.
  ['Frank', new Date(2007,11,28)],
  ['Floyd', new Date(2005,3,13)],
  ['Fritz', new Date(2011,6,1)]
]);*/

      var materialOptions = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Enrolled courses Details'
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Completion Percentage',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Courses'
        },
        bars: 'vertical'
      };
      var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row rounded">
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will be very grateful if someone could say why I am getting invalid row index error while I am trying to insert a string in data.setCell(); method. I saw similar error but couldn't find the reason.

Comment: Please add the error message in text form to your question and explain where it comes from

Comment: Thanks for you valuable feedback. Actually my question description contains the error message and i have explained where it occurred data.setCell();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data table method `setCell` takes the following arguments...

```
setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, value);
```

you're trying to pass row values, which is causing the error...

```
data.setCell(course_name,course_percent);
```

instead, don't add the rows initially, (remove --> `data.addRows(20);`)
add them once you have the values...

see following snippet...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Course Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Completion Percentage');

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {   
    var val = obj[key];
    var course_percent=val.id;
    var course_name=val.fullname;
    data.addRow([course_name,course_percent]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it is really helpful and my chart renders properly with given value